# use functions from other class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I have a number of classes where there are functions inside are almost the same.

Say function x:

```
class A():
    def x_A (self):
        ...
        ...do the same thing
        ...
        run a function that is unique in class A itself, say u_A
        ...
        ...do the same thing
        ...


class B():
    def x_B (self):
        ...
        ...do the same thing
        .. 
        run a function that is unique in class B itself, say u_B
        ...
        ...do the same thing
        ...
```

So I came up with an idea to re-write function x in a new class(say x_C in class C) to replace x_A and x_B. And I just have to import that new class when I need it. something like:

```
import C

class A():
    def x_A (self):
        C.x_C(u_A)

class B():
    def x_B (self):
        C.x_C(u_A)
```

but I am confused of how to pass in the unique function (u_A and u_B) as a variable and make python to run it properly.

```
class C():
    def x_C (self,unique_function):
        ...
        ...do the same thing
        .. 
        run unique_function here
        ...
        ...do the same thing
        ...
```

Thx in advance

## blow is newly edited:

hi trying to specify my question:

I have a number of crawlers, at the end of each I got "run_before_insert" to check if they can run properly.
Currently I just copy and paste this function at end of every finished crawler with some edits.
But now I would like to simplify my code by importing "run_before_insert" from other files, and then comes my questions.

```
def run_before_insert(self):
        try:
            #store_list = []
            comp_name = 'HangTen'
            start = time.time()
            print('{} runBeforeInsert START'.format(comp_name), '\n')
            
            ###Here is the part where small edits in the function:
            store_list = self.get_stores_2()
            ###the rest is the same

            script_info = {}
            running_time = round(time.time() - start,2)
            total = str(len(store_list))
            script_info['running_time'] = running_time
            script_info['total_stores'] = total

            print('\n{} total stores : {}'.format(comp_name,script_info['total_stores']), '\n')
            print('{} running time : {}'.format(comp_name,script_info['running_time']), '\n')
            print('{} runBeforeInsert Done'.format(comp_name), '\n')
            print('\n')

            return script_info

        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            script_info = {}
            script_info['running_time'] = '--'
            script_info['total_stores'] = 'error'

            return script_info
            print(e)
```

Here is my code with reference to @juanpa.arrivillaga:

```
class run_pkg_class():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
   
    def run_before_insert(self, store_function, company_name):
        try:
           
            comp_name = company_name
            start = time.time()
            print('{} runBeforeInsert START'.format(comp_name), '\n')
            
            ### 
            store_list = store_function() 
            ###

            script_info = {}
            running_time = round(time.time() - start,2)
            total = str(len(store_list))
            script_info['running_time'] = running_time
            script_info['total_stores'] = total

            print('\n{} total stores : {}'.format(comp_name,script_info['total_stores']), '\n')
            print('{} running time : {}'.format(comp_name,script_info['running_time']), '\n')
            print('{} runBeforeInsert Done'.format(comp_name), '\n')
            print('\n')

            return script_info

        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            script_info = {}
            script_info['running_time'] = '--'
            script_info['total_stores'] = 'error'

            return script_info
            print(e)
```

and import above into hangten crawler class:

```
def run_before_insert2(self):
        rp = run_pkg_class()
        rp.run_before_insert(self.get_id())
```

In this hangTen case, self.get_stores_2() will return a list.

"TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" occur while running.

Not sure for the reason

Comment: `import C` doesn't import a class, it imports a _module_ (usually the one defined by the source file `C.py`). Also, if `C` _is_ a class rather than a module, and `x_C` is a normal method in that class, you can't call `C.x_C`, you have to construct an instance, `c = C()`, and then you can call `c.x_C`.

Comment: Meanwhile, this would probably be a lot easier to explain with concrete, meaningful names instead of things like `C` and `x_C`.

Answer (score 0):

Python functions are first-class objects. They are like any other attribute. Just pass them directly:

```
import C

class A:
    def x_A (self):
        C.x_C(self.u_A)

class B:
    def x_B (self):
        C.x_C(self.u_B)
```

And in `C`, you just call it like so:

```
unique_function()
```

Given that `C` apparently doesn't care about the state in `A` and `B` though, I suspect these things shouldn't be classes to begin with.

Comment: The reason I would like to create a class C is that there might be other similar functions to run in class A and B in the future. Or maybe there is other better practices?

Comment: You can have functions that aren't in classes and aren't tied to objects.

Comment: @Pete yes a module level function seems eminently appropriate here. It's hard to give much more concrete advice without more concrete details.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't even need to import a module every time. Instead, you can create a basic class from which other classes will inherit the function. For example, classes B and C inherit function "power" from class A.

```
class A:
    """ Example of class A """
    def __init__(self):
        self.num1 = num1

    def power(self, num):
        return num**3

class B (A):
    """ Example of class B"""

    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        super().__init__(num1)
        self.num2 = num2
        self.power_num1 = self.power(num1)

class C(A):
    """ Example of class C"""

    def __init__(self, num1, num2, num3):
        super().__init__(num1)
        self.num2 = num2
        self.num3 = num3

    def power_total(self):
        print(self.power(self.num1) + self.power(self.num2)
              + self.power(self.num3))
```

Examples of use:

```
>>> c = C(1, 2, 3)
>>> c.power_total()
36
>>> b = B(2, 4)
>>> b.power_num1
8
```